# VBScript Remote WMI Call "Error:0 'Permission denied: 'GetObject"

Tags: vbscript, wmi, windows-authentication, rpc, solarwinds-orion

I am receiving the following error when trying to do a remote WMI call:

> **Failed to parse the script. Error: Source:'Microsoft VBScript runtime error'
> Line 4 Char:1
> Error:0 'Permission denied: 'GetObject''**

If I run the following code pointing to my local machine, I receive no error. However, when I run the code pointing to a remote machine I get the error above.

```
strComputer = "COMPUTER-X"
strService = "Netlogon"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from WIN32_Service")

For Each objService in colRunningServices
    if objService.DisplayName = strService then
        if objService.State = "Running" then
            Context.SetValue 1
        else
            Context.SetValue 0
        End If
    Else
    End If
Next
```

I have tried the following:

1. Turn off firewall on remote machine.
2. Change HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\RPC "RestrictRemoteClients" from 2 to 1 on remote machine
3. Change Group Policy Computer Configuration\Admistrative Templates\System\RPC "Restrict Unauthenticated RPC clients" and "Enable RPC Endpoint Mapper Client Authenticatin" settings.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
 Security ID:  S-1-0-0
 Account Name:  -
 Account Domain:  -
 Logon ID:  0x0

Logon Information:
 Logon Type:  3
 Restricted Admin Mode: -
 Virtual Account:  No
 Elevated Token:  No

Impersonation Level:  Impersonation

New Logon:
 Account Name:  COMPUTER-X
 Account Domain:  contosco.co
 Logon ID:  0x22BA30
 Linked Logon ID:  0x0
 Network Account Name: -
 Network Account Domain: -
 Logon GUID:  {63f2b1e0-7c0c-3dc0-ba09-aec258b06623}

Answer (score 0):

The computer doing the query was connecting to the remote machine with is computer account (CONTOSCO\COMPUTER-X) and it did not have the correct permissions to execute winmgmts commands. After adding the computer account (CONTOSCO\COMPUTER-X) to the local administrators group, the query executed with no issue!

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/user-account-control-and-wmi